# How can I create a circular separation effect with gradient in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image]

I want to create effect similar to below  image in illustrator..How can i do it.. I think i can make it through pathfinder but i am unable to produce

Comment: Greetings! It would be of great help to us all if you edited your question to include some images of what you have tried. Saves everyone time, and increases the chances that you will get a good answer.

Comment: As suggested by Random please provide us with what you have tried.  Are you having issues with the shape or creating the gradient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create 2 identical circles. One with stroke width of 20 and the other one 10. Expand their appearance and align them like that:

[image]

Then select both and click Divide in the Pathfinder.

[image]

Then select and delete the parts that you don't need:

[image]

Then select all black parts and unite them in order to create one solid shape.

Done!

Comment: I would just use subtract. Before subtracting I would  delete the bottom part of the cutting circle as this would be less cleanup and makes a simpler shape.